# Rest api to get all details of AWS marketplace public listing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-marketplace

Is there any Rest api to get all details(including the AMI image details) of AWS marketplace public listing?

For Example:-

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-lk3liabqn4x2i?sr=0-1&ref_=beagle&applicationId=AWSMPContessa

I want all details if I provide any identifier from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the EC2 API [DescribeImages action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImages.html) and set the `Owner` parameter to `aws-marketplace` to output all the AWS Marketplace-owned AMIs and their details in a specific region.

Here is an example [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html) command that does that:

```
aws ec2 describe-images \
  --region us-east-1 \
  --owners aws-marketplace
```

With AWS CLI, you can also use [filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html) to filter the list.